# set manipulation calculate mapping

Tags: algorithm, set

Assume we have 2 sets,   A= {'a', 'b', 'c'},  B={1,2,3}, there is another set C which contains combination of items from A and B. for example:  C={('a',1), ('a',2), ('a',3), ('c',1), ('b',2)}.

**What's the best way to get all the items from A which maps all the items from set B in set C?**

In the example C above, the result is {'a'}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary/hash set of lists: `HashSet<A,List<B>>`:

Now, iterate the set `C`, for each item `(a,b)` in `C`, add `b` to the list mapped to element `a`.

When you are done iterating, iterate the keys of this set, and yield all keys that has an associated list of size `|B|`.

Pseudo Code:

```
histogram = {} //empty dictionary/hash set
for ((a,b) in C):
    if (a is not a key in histogram):
        histogram.put(a,[])
    histogram[a].append(b)
for each key a in histogram:
    if (histogram[a].size() == B.size()):
        yield a
```

This can also be done nicely (and scalable) in [map-reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce):

```
map(C):
  for each c=(a,b) in C:
      emit(a,b)//a is the key
reduce(a,list<B>):
  count = 0
  for each b in list:
      count += 1
  if count == B.size():
      emit(a)
```

**Note:**

This solution assumes `C` is a set, which is a subset of `AxB`, if this is not the case, some modifications are required - but the same idea still holds.

Comment: Why not increment a counter in a `HashSet<A,int>`?  If these are sets we're guaranteed no duplicates.